# Comma separated field in a PostgreSQL (PostGIS) SELECT query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, csv

I've polygons and points in a PostGIS database. Let's say there are red, blue, green and yellow points. This information is saved in a field named 'color'. What I want to do is to select all polygons without red points:

```
CREATE VIEW polygons_without_red_points AS
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (gid)
polygons.*
FROM
polygons LEFT JOIN points
ON ST_Contains(polygons.geom, points.geom)
WHERE points.geom IS NULL OR points.color != red;
```

Duplicate geometries should be removed from the result set! Unfortunately, I do not know how to save the color information in the polygons. Is there a way to create a comma separated field?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that, in a polygon with points of yellow and green colours, you'd have a field that read "yellow,green" ?

Comment: Do you mean polygon without any red, or polygon with at least another color (regardless of the reds)?

Comment: If a polygon object contains points with color values yellow and green, this information should be saved in a field of the polygon table (yellow, green). All polygon objects that contain points with color value red should be ignored.

Comment: check out array_agg

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560946/postgresql-group-concat-equivalent